On the order of evaluation when calling a function
According to cppreference:

“When calling a function (whether or not the function is inline, and
whether or not explicit function call syntax is used), every value
computation and side effect associated with any argument expression,
or with the postfix expression designating the called function, is
sequenced before execution of every expression or statement in the
body of the called function”.

Could anybody please explain what does it mean: “or with the postfix expression designating the called function”, and give an example.

The function call expressions consists of two parts: The function to call, and its arguments. The "postfix expression designating the called function" is likely the expression for the function to call. In many cases this is just the name of the function itself, but it can also be a more complex expression (in C++ the most common is the member selection, like an_object.a_member_function).

What is a "postfix expression"?
C++ operator precedence is not very intuitive on the syntax level. The items with highest precedence is stuff like identifiers (variable/function names) or integer constants (like 123). They belong to the group primary expressions.
The second highest precedence is the group of operators that are unary postfix operators, perhaps most obvious things like i++ where the ++ is the postfix increment operator. But other operators like array subscripting [ ] and function call ( ) are also postfix operators.
For function calls specifically, the formal syntax goes like (C++20 7.6.1):

postfix-expression ( expression-listopt )

So in this case "postfix" counterintuitively refers to everything to the left of the ( ) function call, since the function call operator is one of the postfix operators. And if we ignore cppreference and go read the actual standard, then it says (C++20 7.6.1.2 §8):

The postfix-expression is sequenced before each expression in the expression-list and any default argument. The initialization of a parameter, including every associated value computation and side effect, is indeterminately sequenced with respect to that of any other parameter. [Note: All side effects of argument evaluations are sequenced before the function is entered (see 6.9.1). —end note]


Order of evaluation during function calls
Lets cook up an example with an array of function pointers farr:
void some_func (int i)
{
  do_something(i++);
}

void (*farr[])(int) = { some_func, ... }

And then we call a function using that array:
farr[i++] (i++)

Then the "postfix expression"  farr[i++] contains a side effect i++ (or it could contain a value computation i). What your quote does not mention is how that part is sequenced in relation to the argument evaluation (i++).
The part from the standard that I quoted does, however. "The postfix-expression is sequenced before each expression in the expression-list". So the left i++ is executed before the right one and that is well-defined.
Your quoted text however is just somewhat unhelpfully saying that both the farr[i++] (postfix expression) and the (i++) (argument expression) are sequenced before do_something(i++); inside the function body. From the note in the quoted standard "All side effects of argument evaluations are sequenced before the function is entered".

Just to add on to the answer: The sequencing rule is not present before C++17 where farr[i++] (i++) has undefined behavior instead.

Similarly it is UB in C as well. One of the few things later C++ standards have done well is trying to weed out needless UB from the language. C never had such an ambition, it rather likes to embrace various forms of UB, as if it should be preserved for nostalgia reasons alone. i=i++; being the most obvious example.


the postfix expression designating the called function

This is the expression left of the parentheses in the function call expression.
For example:
void f(int& i) { if(i) i++; }

int main() {
    int i = 0;
    (i++, f)(i);
    return i;
}

Here the postfix expression of the function call expression (i++, f)(i) is (i++, f).
The quote says that that (i++, f) is fully evaluated, including any side effects, before if(i) i++; inside the call to f, meaning that there will not be any undefined behavior and the program is guaranteed to return 2.

The more relevant elephant in the room is however how (i++, f) is sequenced in relation to the expression list (i). The quote in the question doesn't address that.

@Lundin The argument is taken by-reference here, so that has no impact on the behavior in this case.

Isn't the argument evaluation of (i) still a value computation regardless of that?

@Lundin Yes, but the value computation only determines the identity of the object that the result of the i lvalue expression refers to and that is always the same regardless of the evaluation of other expressions in the example. There is also no UB associated with that value computation being unsequenced with side effects on the object.

But suppose i is a pointer? Then i++ would have affected the outcome of the value computation. I think this part is probably more important to understand especially since C is different here. I'll try to cook up an answer of my own.

@Lundin Well, yes, if you pass by pointer there is an additional lvalue-to-rvalue conversion on the argument (which would then be passed by-value again) which implies an access to an object. There is no access to an object or value computation on an object when evaluating a glvalue expression for binding to a reference without such a conversion applied to it. There is nothing really comparable to this in C.

In C it is just that there's a sequence point after the argument evaluation before the function call and that's it. Everything else that happens before that is indeterminately sequenced (including parameters versus other parameters which is indeterminately sequenced in C++ too). But C++ seems to have at least made an effort to sequence the postfix expression vs the arguments (during C++11 somewhere?) which is at least a slight improvement.

@Lundin "(including parameters versus other parameters which is indeterminately sequenced in C++ too)": Only since C++17, they were unsequenced before that. C++17 also added that the postfix expression is evaluated before any argument expression.
